# What did the lunar cycle have to do with the killer?

Tags: red-dragon

One of the first things we learn about the killer is that they only kill during a certain time in the moon's phases, which sets up the need to track the killer down before their next murder during the next lunar cycle.

Having finished the movie, though, what does the moon have to do with the killer or their motivations?

> I caught the bit about his issues with his grandmother and women in general, his fixation on the Red Dragon painting, the planned transformation into a deity, the need for an audience and seeing the life in the victim's eyes, but none of that seems to have anything to do with the moon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Because he feels a 'special relationship with the moon', and perhaps wants to appear black in the moonlight when covered in blood.

See the theory that Hannibal has, when talking to Will, in the novel *Red Dragon*:

> '**Because, my dear Will, if this pilgrim feels a special relationship with the moon, he might like to go outside and look at it. Before he tidies himself up, you understand? Have you seen blood in the moonlight, Will? It appears quite black. Of course, it keeps the distinctive sheen.** If one were nude, say, it would be better to have outdoor privacy for that sort of thing. One must show some consideration for the neighbours, hmmmmm?
>
> 'You think the yard might be a factor when he selects victims?'
>
> 'Oh yes. And there will be more victims, of course.'